# Drupal WebForm - Access denied after submitting form after Drupal Update:

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

We’re running on Drupal 7.73 and WebForm 7.x-3.30 – for a while now since the 7.75 to 7.77 Drupal release, we’ve been unable to update Drupal successfully. As every time a user submits a form on the site, we’re getting an “Access Denied” message. If you’re logged in as Admin it works. I believe it could have something to do with the “success message” that’s being displayed and that in theory, a redirect to a success page could fix it. However, as we have many forms across several sites, it is not practical to go this route.

For two years we have had no problem updating Drupal to latest and no issues with WebForm so this is a new issue.

Can anyone please assist in providing a solution for this as we are unable to update to implement the latest security fixes?

Your assistance is appreciated

Comment: What is the form set to do after submission? Do you have any other modules enabled that integrate with webform? Also, you might want to reference your issue in the module issue queue. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3190795

Comment: It displays a success message (so no redirect to a thank you for submitting page).
And yes, I submitted my question there as well, but no feedback or replies, hence the reason I'm submitting it here as well. Hopefully for a solution...
This is my post on the issue queue https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3190795

Comment: Did you check the logs? Did you check permissions? Did you search the [webform issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?text=access+denied&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=any_7.x-&component=All)?

Comment: Logs say Access Denied (after user submitted post). And the permissions say allow posts from Anonymous users. This is the first time this has occurred after Drupal update. Haven't had the need to change any permissions or anything else before.
This is for a standard Enquiry Form built with WebForm.
And yes, I've done a search in the issue queue and nothing there (especially recently).

Comment: Did you try to rebuild permission ?